# Unexpected window position move when executing selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My position on the window unexpectedly moves when I use the ui Select function of the selenium during testing. This is the code that I am talking about:

```
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

    field_select = Select(self.browser.find_element_by_id("field-select"))
    field_select.select_by_visible_text("First Name")
```

Here is my HTML (just CTRL+F  'id="field-select"'):

```
<div id="crew-menu-header"> <!-- START id="crew-menu-header" -->
        <strong>USERS</strong>
        <h3 class="color-msmi-green">Create and Update users.</h3>
    </div> <!-- END id="crew-menu-header" -->
    <div ng-controller="itemListController">
        <div id="crew-menu-body" class="form-horizontal admin-screens-body"> <!-- START id="crew-menu-body" -->
            <div class="form-group negate-margin-bottom"> <!-- START class="form-group negate-margin-bottom" -->
                <div class="col-lg-12"> <!-- START class="col-lg-10 profile-border" -->
                    <div class="form-group" id="search-filter-container"> <!-- START class="form-group search-filter-container" -->
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="input-group-addon input-label negate-padding-left">Search:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-form" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search here..." ng-keyup="search(apiGetItems, $event)" auto-complete ui-items="searchItems">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="input-group-addon input-label">Search by:</label>
                                <select id="field-select" class="form-control input-form" ng-model="searchList" ng-options="x as x.label for x in searchFilters" ng-change="searchFilter()" ng-init="searchList=searchFilters[0]"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <button class="btn form-control btn-msmi-blue" ng-click="clearSearch()" id="clear-sort">Clear</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- END class="form-group" -->
                    <table class="table table-condensed"> <!-- START class="table table-condensed" -->
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <!-- Table Headers declared in an array via angular -->
                            <th ng-repeat="x in tableHeaders">
                                <label ng-class="checkSortable(x.url)" ng-click="itemSort(x.url, x.field, $event)">
                                    [[x.name]]
                                    <span ng-if="x.url" class="caret [[ x.class ]]" ng-click="dynamicCaret($event)" id="sort_[[ x.id ]]"></span>
                                </label> 
                                <span ng-if="x.url">
                                    <span ng-if="orderPosition(x.field)" class="order-attributes">
                                        <span  ng-click="removeOrder(x.field, $event)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove Sort" id="remove_[[ x.id ]]"></span>
                                        <span id="priority_[[ x.id ]]">[[ orderPosition(x.field) ]]</span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            <th class="text-center"><label>Options</label></th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-if="noRecord">
                                <td colspan="[[ tableHeadersLength ]]" class="text-center">[[ noRecordMessage ]] <!-- in the search --></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="x in items" ng-if="!noRecord">
                                <td>[[x.id]]</td>
                                <td>[[x.user_code]]</td>
                                <td>[[x.first_name]] [[x.middle_name]] [[x.last_name]]</td>
                                <td>Group</td>
                                <td>[[x.is_active]]</td>
                                <td>[[x.updated_by.user_code]]</td>
                                <td>[[ x.date_updated ]]</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                    <a href="#/update/[[ x.id ]]"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update"></span></a>
                                    <span ng-if="x.is_active === 'Active'" ng-click="toggleDynamicModal(x.id, true)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Deactivate" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>
                                    <span ng-if="x.is_active === 'Inactive'" ng-click="toggleDynamicModal(x.id, false)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Activate" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> <!-- END class="table table-condensed" -->
                    <div ng-include="'/static/html/pagination.html'"></div>
                </div> <!-- START class="col-lg-12 profile-border" -->
                <!-- <aside> --> <!-- START aside -->
                    <!-- <div class="col-lg-2"> --> <!-- START class="col-lg-2" -->
                        <!-- <div id="profile-sidebar">  --><!-- START id="profile-sidebar" -->
                            <!-- <a href=""><button class="btn form-control" ng-hide="!isChecked()" ng-click="deleteMultiple()">DELETE</button></a>
                            <a href="#/add"><button class="btn form-control">ADD</button></a>
                            <a href=""><button class="btn form-control" ng-click="close()">EXIT</button></a> -->
                        <!-- </div> --> <!-- END id="profile-sidebar" -->
                    <!-- </div> --> <!-- END class="col-lg-2" -->
                <!-- </aside> --> <!-- END aside -->
            </div> <!-- END class="form-group negate-margin-bottom" -->
        </div> <!-- END id="crew-menu-body" -->

        <confirmation-modal title="Please Confirm" visible="showModal"> <!-- START delete-modal -->
            <div id="notifications">
                <div ng-if="!notifications">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        [[ statement ]]
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteItem(id, 'user_code', apiDelete)" data-dismiss="modal" ng-if="operation" id="deactivate">Deactivate</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="individualUpdate($event, id,'is_active', true, apiUpdate, x)" data-dismiss="modal" ng-if="!operation" id="restore">Restore</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="notifications">
                    <div ng-repeat="x in deleteArray">
                        <div> <span class="item-notification">[[ x.name ]]</span> - has been deactivated <button class="btn btn-default btn-msmi-blue undo-button" ng-click="individualUpdate($event, x.id,'is_active', true, apiUpdate, x)">UNDO</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </confirmation-modal> <!-- END delete-modal -->

        <div id="crew-menu-footer"> <!-- START id="crew-menu-footer" -->
            <div class="form-group screens-footer"> <!-- START class="form-group screens-footer" -->
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-6">
                    <a href=""><button class="btn form-control" ng-hide="!isChecked()" ng-click="toggleModalMultiple()" id="deactivate-modal">DEACTIVATE</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <a href="#/add"><button class="btn form-control" id="add-page">ADD</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <a href=""><button class="btn form-control" ng-click="close()" id="exit">EXIT</button></a>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- END class="form-group screens-footer" -->
        </div> <!-- END id="crew-menu-foote"r -->
    </div>
```

JUST MIND about the field select as my point is. Whenever the line 'field_select.select_by_visible_text("First Name")' is executed the browser view automatically goes to the bottom of the page. I proved that theory by removing that line that I just mentioned and nothing happend. When I put it back it moves to the bottom again.

I am using python 3.5, django 1.9, selenium 2.52.0, firefox browser

Comment: Is your `field-select` element located at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Actuall no, it is at the top. I will post my HTML as well in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as it should work. The `select_by_visible_text()` [would issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/91ed4405abcf4d53e399baa3bb6d06ff5d2dd0e2/py/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py#L211) a `CLICK` webdriver COMMAND for an appropriate option. According to the [webdriver specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#h-element-click), when an element is clicked it is first *scrolled into view*:

> The Element Click command scrolls into view the element and then
>   attempts to click the centre of its visible area. In case the element
>   is not displayed, an element not visible error is returned.

Comment: So in short, It's natural for the position move to occur? because it is finding that certain option from the select?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada yeah, it's natural for selenium to scroll the page to move the option into view when selecting it. Sounds like your case..

Comment: This explains it! Anyway the real problem is I get the "element not clickable at point selenium" error because of my navbar fixed suddenly blocking the element that needs to be clicked after the window move but at least you have explained it well.

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada thanks! You can try maximizing the browser window and see if it helps to tackle the overlay.

Comment: Already did that, I just made the navbar static when I'm testing it. To fix the errors and failures on the test